# Is it possible to insert a Bookmark in Google Docs to a Table Cell/Table/Text via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, insert, google-docs, bookmarks

Is it possible to insert a Bookmark at a table cell or text in Google Docs using Google Apps Script by e.g. specifying the table cell? From the documentation I understand that you need the absolute position which is bound to the cursor. What if I want to set Bookmarks at specified tables automatically. Is that not possible? Here the URL of the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark

And if so is it possible to link the inserted bookmark with a table cell using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Were you able to test it with `newPosition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bookmark without using cursors, you can do it via Position class. Since `getCursor` returns `Position`, we need to find other methods that returns the same, and that is `newPosition` which only requires the element and offset (if needed). See code below:

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  // find the text element
  var textElement = body.findText("<HERE>").getElement();
  // create position using the element
  var position = doc.newPosition(textElement, 0)
  // addBookmark using the created position
  doc.addBookmark(position);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- For other objects, it should be doable as long as you can get the element and use it to get their positions.

#### Reference:

- [newPosition](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newpositionelement,-offset)